# The focused hint bar colour of edit text is not changing

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, android-edittext

Want to change the focused hint Edittext colour but it is not changing. What's the matter ? Have used all the attributes in the edit Text theme but yet it's not changing.I have changed the parent theme from MaterialComponents to App Compat , is it becoz of that ?

[image]

This is my themes.xml file.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.QuizApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/font10</item>
    </style>

    <style name="heading_name" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/font1</item>
        <item name="textFillColor">#2B0031</item>
    </style>

    <style name="EditTextTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/purple_gray</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/purple_gray</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/purple_gray</item>
        <item name="hintTextColor">@color/purple_gray</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/purple_gray</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeErrorColor">@color/purple_gray</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.QuizApp.NoActionBarAndStatusBar" >
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/font10</item>
    </style>

    <style name="progressBarBlue" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorAccent">#4568dc</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.QuizApp.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="Theme.QuizApp.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

This is the activity_main.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/screen_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <TextView
        style="@style/heading_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/font1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:shadowColor="#450750"
        android:shadowDx="1.5"
        android:shadowDy="1.5"
        android:shadowRadius="1.6"
        android:text="Quiz App !"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHighlight="#8F22A1"
        android:textColorHint="#7F1491"
        android:textSize="55sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="50dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="100dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font3"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Welcome ! "
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Please Enter Your Name "
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>
            
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">


                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Name"
                    tools:text="Nandini"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:shadowColor="@color/purple_gray"
                    android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme"
                    android:textColorHighlight="@color/purple_gray"
                    android:textColorLink="@color/purple_gray"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/purple_gray"
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/purple_gray"
                    android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/purple_gray"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/purple_gray"/>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_start"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Start Quiz"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:elevation="100dp"
                android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    
</LinearLayout>
```

This is MainActivity.kt file.

```
package com.nandini.android.quizapp


import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Window
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val btn_start : Button =findViewById(R.id.btn_start)
        val et_name : EditText=findViewById(R.id.et_name)
        btn_start.setOnClickListener {
            if(et_name.text.isEmpty())
            {
                et_name.setError("")
                Toast.makeText(this, "Enter name",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }else{
                val intent = Intent(this,QuizQuestionActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(Constants.USER_NAME,et_name.text.toString())
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Try to use the material `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText` instead of `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText`

Comment: It is still not changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would start using the Material Design library in order to be up to date.

So I would add in my build.gradle (app) :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
```

Then your style should look something like this:

```
<style name="Theme.QuizApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceSubtitle1">@style/TextAppearance.App.test</item>

        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance.App.test" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1">
        <item name="hintTextColor">@color/purple_gray</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/purple_gray</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/purple_gray</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/purple_gray</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/purple_gray</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeErrorColor">@color/purple_gray</item>
    </style>
```

Don't know how your design should look like in the XML so I just left the remaining attributes as it was in the style.

and your MainActivity should become:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val btn_start: Button = findViewById(R.id.btn_start)
        val et_name: TextInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.et_name)

        btn_start.setOnClickListener {
            if (et_name.editText?.editableText.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                et_name.setError("")
                Toast.makeText(this, "Enter name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }else{
                val intent = Intent(this,QuizQuestionActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(Constants.USER_NAME,et_name.text.toString())
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Lastly, in your activity layout you will use that style we created (You will have to adjust that on your project):

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/et_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Default"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.App.test"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/default_edit_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                     />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Let me know if it worked, In my small test project it looks good :)

My small suggestions in general are:

1. Do not to use findViewById since it is not good for performance for the app if you get in the future a lot of views inside your XML. I would suggest you to use viewBinding or DataBinding.
2. Try to add the same amount of spaces between your code so that it looks cleaner
3. Try to extract your Strings, dimensions into xml so that you can re-use them here you can find an article about it https://suragch.medium.com/using-dimens-xml-in-android-10dec2fe485c and one for strings https://riptutorial.com/android/example/13829/working-with-strings-xml-file

Comment: It worked for me. Thank you so much.